# Routing VPN Through VMWARE (Macosx - Windows)

Tags: windows, macos, routes, vmware, intranet

I have a mac running OS X that I need to connect to my company intranet. They have a specific program to do that and it only runs on Windows. I created a windows virtual machine with vmware and I connected it to the VPN.

**No, I can't use an alternative program in OS X to connect - like IPSec(protocol), AT&T, etc - and I don't want to reverse engineer the company's tool.**

What I need to do now is route the OS X network connection through the windows VM.

Vmware already created a virtual network interface to connect between Windows and OS X.

OS X:

```
$ifconfig vmnet8

vmnet8: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500

ether 00:50:56:c0:00:08

inet 172.16.27.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 172.16.27.255
```

I can ping the Windows 7 VM from OS X:

```
$ ping 172.16.27.2

 |                  |             |                  |
 |                  | vmware(NAT) |                  |
 |Mac (172.16.27.1) |<----------->|Win(172.16.27.2)  |
 |                  |             |                  |
```

The company's tool created a virtual interface called "Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2" that contains the company's intranet IP:

```
Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::c1ab:2fe6:40f5:5fa2%14
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.8.15.150
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : localdomain
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::7cd7:a40c:336a:69ae%11
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.27.132
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.27.2
```

How can I access "10.8.15.150" from OS X? How do I make it "magically" route network traffic through the Windows VM into the VPN?

Answer (score 0):

You could run an HTTP proxy in the Windows VM and configure your OS X network connection to route traffic through the proxy.

Comment: Why if I won't use HTTP ?  Any kind of request to 10.*(In Macosx) should route to my actual intranet IP.